# How to pass params using remote_to_function in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm writing a plugin for my redmine and **I need to pass a param from my view to my controller**. I'm trying to pass the param `@repository.url` which already exists on my erb.html file.

Bellow are the code which I'm trying to work. Please, what am I doing wrong? :

**_navigation.erb.html**

```
<% if User.current.allowed_to?(:view_repository, @project) -%>
    <div style="float: left; width: auto; padding-right: 1%">  
    <%= button_to_function l(:gerar_build_project), remote_function(:action => 'exec_client', :controller => 'GerarVersao', :with => "'id=' + $('@repository.url').value")%>
    </div>
```

**gerar_versao_controller.rb**

```
def exec_client(url_branch)
.
.
.
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you.

```
<%= button_to_function l(:gerar_build_project), remote_function(:action => 'exec_client', :controller => 'GerarVersao', :with => "'id=' + $('#{@repository.url}').value") %>
```

Comment: That did not work. I debugged the system and when I clicked on button nothing happened. This happens only I put the parameter **:with** in the clause, if I remove the parameter, my clause is called normally. I'm suspecting this method is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, it is deprecated as of ROR 3.0.9

Comment: So, do you know how can I replace the remote_function to call a my function in controller?